# PDB - stepping out of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb, ipdb

Can I step out of a function after stepping into it with `step` while using pdb / ipdb debugger?

And if there's no such option - what is the fastest way to get out of the stepped-in function?

Answer (score 88):

As mentioned by [Arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2258249/arthur) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565776/pdb-stepping-out-of-a-function#comment84133787_48566000), you can use `r(eturn)` to run execution to the end of the current function and then stop, which almost steps out of the current function. Then enter `n(ext)` once to complete the step out, returning to the caller.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-return).

```
(Pdb) ?r
r(eturn)
        Continue execution until the current function returns.
```

Comment: `r` then `n`, got it!

Comment: And you can use [`retval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-retval) debugger command to examine the return value.

Answer (score 12):

`step` will continue the execution. To move up and down the callstack, you can use `up` (move up to the calling function), and then `down` to go back the other way.

Have a look at the doc: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-step

Comment: I would like to continue the execution until the current running function (the one I stepped into) is finished, something like `until` does for loops

Comment: well, the doc quite clearly list `r(eturn)` which does exactly what you are asking for

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for. Thought `r(eturn)` is just a synonym  to a regular `return`!

Comment: You might want to edit or delete this answer, because it currently doesn't answer the (since edited) question as asked

Answer (score 5):

You can just add a breakpoint outside the function and continue until you reach it. For example, if the call to your function is at line 14, you can:

```
(Pdb) b 15
(Pdb) c
```